# Can't understand event bubbling in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list inside a container which has classes assigned to `li` based on its type. I want to trigger custom event of the form `click.list.type`. So I've written the code as shown in below:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row" id="container">
  <ul class="list-group" id="group">
    <li class="list-group-item type-a">
      <a href="#">Item 1 - Type A</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item type-a">
      <a href="#">Item 2 - Type A</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item type-b">
      <a href="#">Item 3 - Type B</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item type-b">
      <a href="#">Item 4 - Type B</a>
    </li>
  </ul>    
</div>
```

**JS**

```
//This code will be not be available to user
$('#container').on('click', 'li > a', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();

  var type = $(event.target).closest('li').hasClass('type-a') ? 'typea' : 'typeb';
  triggerMyEvents.call(this,event,'click', type);

})

function triggerMyEvents(event, name, type){
  if(event.target.tagName !== 'A'){
        return;
  }
  $(this).trigger($.Event(name+'.'+type));
}

//API for user
$('#container').on('click.typea', function(event){
//   if(event.target.tagName !== 'A'){
//         return;
//   }
  alert("Type A: " +event.target.tagName);
}).on('click.typeb', function(event){    
//   if(event.target.tagName !== 'A'){
//         return;
//   }
  alert("Type B: " +event.target.tagName);
});
```

**CSS**

```
html,body{
  height:100%;
}

#container{
  height:100%;
  background: red
}

#group{
  background: green;
  height: 300px;
}
```

Everthing works as expected except that on click of `ul` (the green area) or `div#container` (red area),the above events are triggered. Putting a check on listeners solves the problem (the commented code). But I don't want to repeat writing the check code where ever the listener is used.

Can anybody help me out?

JS BIN: http://jsbin.com/xelojujeva/1/

Comment: Always post your code in the question.

Comment: Please include the code directly in the question. If JSBin went down, the question would be worthless.

Comment: That jsbin hurts my eyes.

Comment: @artm It's just for demonstration.

Comment: You are missing the `'li > a'` argument in your second and third listeners that are present on the first and do the "check" for you.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I'm trying to make an API similar to that of bootstrap where they don't use extra arguments or filters

Answer (score 1):

This isn't anything to do with event bubbling, this is simply down to how event namespacing works in jQuery. The purpose of a namespace is to allow filtering on events e.g.

```
$('#container').on('click.myPlugin', function() {
    // code specific to myPlugin
});
...
// trigger myPlugin click event handler only
$('#container').trigger('click.myPlugin');
```

However, the filtering works from top-down approach therefore `trigger('click')` would fire *all* registered click event handlers (regardless of namespace) - that's pretty much what's happening here. There are a number of ways to fix this, the most obvious one is to apply the exact same filter you applied in the previous `click` handler

```
$('#container').on('click.typeA', 'li > a', ...).on('click.typeB', 'li > a', ...);
```

However, a better approach would be to not apply the second events to the `#container` element at all but instead call a function

```
//This code will be not be available to user
var self = this;
$('#container').on('click', 'li > a', function(evt){
    evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var type = $(event.target).closest('li').hasClass('type-a') ? 'typea' : 'typeb';
    self[type + 'Clicked'](evt);
});

function typeaClicked(evt) {
    alert('Type A: ' + evt.target.tagName);
}
function typebClicked() {
    alert('Type B: ' + evt.target.tagName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by using `type.click.list` in place of `click.list.type`

```
//This code will be not be available to user
$('#container').on('click', 'li > a', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();

  var type = $(event.target).closest('li').hasClass('type-a') ? 'typea' : 'typeb';
  triggerMyEvents.call(this,event, type, 'click');

})

function triggerMyEvents(event, type, name){
  if(event.target.tagName !== 'A'){
        return;
  }
  $(this).trigger($.Event(type+'.list.'+name));
}

//API for user
$('#container').on('typea.list.click', function(event){
  alert("Type A: " +event.target.tagName);
}).on('typeb.list.click', function(event){    
  alert("Type B: " +event.target.tagName);
});
```